# JsonMappingException AJAX Request on not used class

Tags: ajax, json, jax-rs

I am using jax-rs to send an object via POST to my java bean:

```
$scope.saveConge = function() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        method:         "POST",
        url:            "rest/saisieConge/saveCongeView?cid="+conversationId,
        contentType:    "application/json",
        data:           JSON.stringify($scope.popupConge),
        async:          false,
        success:        function(response){
            if(!response) alert("Erreur de sauvegarde");
        }
    });
}
```

In my java bean:

```
@POST
@Path("/saveCongeView")
@Consumes("application/json")
public boolean saveCongeView(CongeViewRest congeViewRest){...}
```

In CongeViewRest I have two properties: Conge and a float. I get a JsonMappingException from jackson on a Class which isn't used in Conge... I don't understand why I get an error on this class since it isn't supposed to be called anywhere... I tried to use this on the classes I use:

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.NONE, getterVisibility = Visibility.NONE, isGetterVisibility = Visibility.NONE)
```

And put `@JsonProperty`on the properties I really need. So now the data sent to the java bean are exactly those I need, but I still got the error on the class I never use...

Thanks for any help !